# Any univeral way to place a common menu in iframe to load from a single location

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, menu

My web site has a common horizontal menu and I'd like to put this into a single html file so I only need to change it in one place.

My solution is to put the menu into an iframe and have a DIV id=menu in the main page. In the menuFrame html I have an onload with this:

```
    <script language="JavaScript">
    function doLoad() {
        window.parent.document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
    }
    </script>
```

This works fine in IE, Safary, Mozilla but not in Chrome.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For various reasons relating to usability and browser support; the better choice is pretty much *always* to not use an iframe for this; but rather include the menu in the text of the page using a server-side language like [PHP](http://php.net) or similar.

If, as occasionally happens, your host doesn't support PHP, it's time to switch hosting services.

As for the code itself, it's pretty simple:

```
<?php include '/path/to/menu.html' ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

iframe is a bad solution.

Does your server support [serverside includes (SSI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)

```
<!--#include virtual="menu.html" -->
```